# SonarQube unable to analyze Xamarin project

Tags: .net, xamarin, sonarqube

I'm trying to use SonarQube developer Edition, locally on my project which is on Xamarin.
The issue that I'm Facing issue that after command dotnet build i get build failed message with

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.401\NuGet.targets(131,5): warning : Unable to find a project to restore! [C:\Users\prabhatk\Documents\XamarinProject\DataCollector\DataCollector.sln]
```

and there are some more errors too, the reason I'm not posting other errors because my sample project for testing SonarQube showed same error but it was able to scan, nd I can see that project on SonarQube.

Comment: Sometimes, I have the same problem when my folder structure on the file system is not the same as a visual representation in Visual Studio, or sometimes when I miss a location where I run `dotnet build` command.

Comment: Are you running `dotnet build` or are you using `msbuild`? `dotnet` 5.x doesn't build Xamarin projects.

Answer (score -1):

Since my sample projects were being scanned by SonarQube, I knew that Xamarin was not the issue, also I knew that only shared code will be scanned by SonarQube, on analyzing errors, I figured it might have to with nuget package. But I'm still not sure what is the actual reason that "dotnet build" was not able to build the project.

I copied the shared code from my project that I wanted to scan and paste in newly created Project, install all the project,

Then followed all the steps provided by SonarQube and I scan that project perfectly.